# Binding of multiple pages in crystal report

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports, .doc

[image]

I am planing to create a web application using vb.net for generating agreemnets of our company with clients ,Its 7 page agreement in .doc format, ,currently we are manually changing the Name,place,mobile number,Amount ect from MS Word. The changes will come only first page and last two pages (page-1,page-6,page-7).So do u think crystal report is the solution for this? I can bind all the pages in crystal report? if not then what is the best way?I need the 7 page agreement after clicking generate button .

Answer (score 0):

Export to Word in Crystal does not produce a real DOC file. It is a RTF file renamed to DOC. Formatting might not be the same as you expect. You can try to use Mail Merge capabilities in Word. Probably not the best solution for  WEB application to use automation , but there will be advantages too. For example , if you use Crystal reports you will need to recreate the Word document in Crystal and update it each time there is a change in the original document.